# root running cron task can't read .txt file generated by www-data user

Tags: linux, bash, cron, root

I have a simple php page that writes a file to my server.

```
// open new file
     $filename = "$name.txt";
    $fh = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($fh, "$name".";"."$abbreviation".";"."$uid".";");
    fclose($fh);
```

I then have a cron job that I know runs as root as test that and need that.

```
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
```

The cronjob is a bash script that can detect the file exists, but it can't seem to read the contents of the file.

```
#!/bin/bash


######################################################
#### Loop through the files and generate coincode ####
######################################################
for file in /home/test/customcoincode/queue/*
    do
    echo $file
    chmod 777 $file
    echo "read file"

    while read -r coinfile; do
      echo $coinfile
    echo "Assign variables from file"

#############################################
#### Set the variables to from the file #####
#############################################

    coinName=$(echo $coinfile | cut -f1 -d\;)
    coinNameAbreviation=$(echo $coinfile | cut -f2 -d\;)
    UId=$(echo $coinfile | cut -f3 -d\;)

    done < $file

    echo "`date +%H:%M:%S` - $coinName : Your Kryptocoin is being compiled!"

    echo $file

    echo "copy $coinName file to generated directory"

    cp -b $file /home/test/customcoincode/generatedCoins/$coinName.txt

    echo "`date +%H:%M:%S` : Delete queue file"

#   rm -f $file



done
```

`echo $file` recognises the file exists

`echo $coinfile` is blank

Yet when I `nano ./coinfile.txt` in terminal I can see clearly there is text in there

I run `ls -l` and I see that the file has the permissions

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data
```

I was under the impression that this would still mean the file can be read by other users?
Do I need to be able to execute the file if i am opening it and reading the contents?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I can expand and show my code if you want, but it was working before when I called a bash script to write the file... and that time it would save the file under root user with rwx for most and then could be read.  But this then caused other issues in the php page, so is not an option.

Comment: well thanks for the downvote and no comment!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're going to need to post more information for people to be able to help you. As it is this question is unanswerable. Please post the contents of your bash script, the crontab, the full path to the file, and the *exact* error you get.

Comment: Hey thank you for the constructive comments :) I have added code in to show the basics of what is going on.  There is no error message, simply that the file is being read as being empty.  full path /home/test/customcoincode/queue/coinfile.txt

Comment: Is the `#!/bin/bash` really preceded by white space in your script, or is that a copy-and-paste error?

Comment: What output do you get if you add `wc $file` immediately before the top of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
 while read -r coinfile; do
 ...
```

I see no indication that you're reading from `$file`. The command

```
read -r coinfile
```

will simply read from standard input (the `-r` merely affects the treatment of backslashes). In a cron job, if I recall correctly, standard input is empty or unavailable, which would explain why `$coinfile` is empty.

If you actually do read from `$file` -- for example, if your real code looks something like:

```
while read -r coinfile; do
    ...
done <$file
```

then you need to show us your entire script, or at least a self-contained version of it that exhibits the problem. Actually, you need to show us your entire script whether that's the problem or not.

http://sscce.org/

Comment: Ok I have included the whole test bash script that I isolated the read problem down to.  Many thanks for your reply... i feel you may want me to add more